# Joomla Cron not finding setting files

Tags: joomla, cron

Running Joomla 3.9.0
Civicrm 5.7.0
PHP 7.0.2

Recently update Civicrm to 5.7.0 - Prior version and my cron job was working fine. Now it hasn't run since November 7th

Run cli.php

`php /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s domain_name.com -u user -p password -e Job -a execute`

Output is

```
PHP Warning:  include_once(/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php on line 118
PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php on line 118
Could not load the settings file at: /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php
```

I have looked at some of the patches. But the patches are older than the version I have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I haven't noticed any problem with CiviCRM 5.7.0 on Joomla 3.9.0 and PHP 7.1.24.
Use only cli.php with Joomla as cron.php has not worked on Joomla since J 3.8.0 (I haven't tested on 3.9.0). Also you are using cron.php incorrectly - it must be called via wget/curl and the URL of cron.php.
cli.php should work with CiviCRM 5.7.0 out of the box.

Comment: Since you state cron.php hasn't worked since 3.8.0, then I guess not using wget/curl doesn't make any difference. How about the cli.php errors I received? Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: Your cli.php command looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php` file. It should be only 12 lines long and look like the following:

```
<?php
define('CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH', '<www root>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php');
$error = @include_once( '<www root>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' );
if ( $error == false ) {
    echo "Could not load the settings file at: <www root>/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
";
    exit( );
}

// Load class loader
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
CRM_Core_ClassLoader::singleton()->register();
```

The 3 paths to `civicrm.settings.php` within `civicrm.config.php` should all be absolute. Your PHP warnings show that `/../..//default/` is in the path, which is incorrect for Joomla. I can't explain how it (or code that is generating it) ended up in your `civicrm.config.php`; this [forum post](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=32046.0.html) might give a clue. If your `civicrm.config.php` is not as per the above, replace it with this, substituting  with the correct path.

Comment: The forum post you pointed is the issue except I have never had a Drupal setup. I checked the latest civicrm-5.7.2-joomla.zip and the civicrm.config.php file is 127 lines, not 12 lines (which I'm guessing is wrong). After coping my previous config & setting.php. I get a new error, db_error, connect failed. Interesting I changed the cron job to use my previous php (5.6.16) and it works once again.

Comment: `administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php` really is only 12 lines on a Joomla installation. Yes there is a `civicrm.config.php` file that is 127 lines (which is really for Drupal due to CiviCRM's Drupal origin) within civicrm.zip in civicrm-5.7.2-joomla.zip however the 12-line civicrm.config.php is created during installation. I just did a clean installation of Joomla and CiviCRM to confirm that this is the case.